# respond.js will prefer media queries over later defined global selectors

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries, respond.js

I found the bug when using and overriding padding in Bootstrap `.jumbotron` classes.

**Description:**
To simplify the problem look at this example to provoke the respond.js bug:

```
.shouldBeGreen {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 50px) {
  .shouldBeGreen {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}


/* Later in the CSS or in another LESS file... */


/* Will be overridden by respond.js */
.shouldBeGreen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Open my following example page in Chrome/FF/Opera/Safari and IE8 (emulated or not) to compare the problem.

http://krnl.de/resources/respond.js-bug/index.html

**Behaviour:**
Respond.js picks all relevant media query parts and puts them **after** the source CSS file which results in overriding all associated selectors defined after the media query.

**Solution:**
I racked my brains about this, but don't have a solution at this point.

Here is my bug report to Respond.js: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/225

Comment: "... which results in overriding all associated selectors defined after the media query." So why don't you put your Media Queries at the end of your CSS file!? And also "Browsers that natively support CSS3 Media Queries are opted-out of running this script as quickly as possible.". Therefore you could limit the script to the older IEs by using Conditional Comments and load a separate stylesheet (if this is easier for you).

Comment: Did you try my example in IE8? Because this thread isn't about how to bypass the problem which I of course already do - it is about the problem itself. And the problem is, respond.js (as a polyfill) behaves different from browser which support media queries natively.

Comment: Yes, I did! "And the problem is, respond.js (as a polyfill) behaves different from browser which support media queries natively." Yes, that is often so when you use polyfills. Some of them have certain restrictions which you have to watch out. Making CSS depending on Javascript isn't "ideal" at all. That's why I do not use such polyfills like 'respond.js' and have a fixed width version for all browsers that do not support MQs (natively)!

Comment: If it behaves different, then the question is why was the polyfill developed in the first place. it should rather be called "a script doing some stuff" than "polyfill", are you with me?

Comment: btw. https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ has the exact same issue.

Comment: What is your complaint? Have you read "[**How's it works**](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#hows-it-work)"? There is described that "... each media query block is appended to the head in order via style elements, and those style elements are enabled and disabled (read: appended and removed from the DOM) ...". This means that every rule will be appended after all so far loaded CSS styles. This is "by design" and not a bug. BTW: It is all good style to write all MQs **after** your default rules (for non-supporting browsers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes you don't write all the stuff by yourself. Sometimes you use a framework, like Bootstrap. You _will_ soon or later run into my problem when you rely on a framework. The point is, Bootstrap recommends the use of Respond.js to enable MQs on non-MQ-enabled systems. And in my opinion it is a bug if Respond.js doesn't consider later defined selectors. At least it doesn't work like the Media Query's spec prescribes it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug but how browser engines work!

Due to the fact that the original CSS has to be loaded first, any JS script is only able to **append** styles to the existing ones. Thus all these styles come at the end - no other way!

You have to keep this in mind when writing your CSS code.
Anyway it is a good design principle to place all your Media Queries at the end after your "default" styles for non-supporting browsers.

Comment: Sorry, this has nothing to do with browser engines. The problem is in the Respond.js library. If it wouldn't append the media-query specific code after the physical CSS file, it wouldn't break.

Comment: "If it wouldn't append the media-query specific code after the physical CSS file, it wouldn't break" and that is exactly what's not possible (caused by how browser engines work). ;-) The rules from inside a `<style>...</style>` and from external CSS files come **always** first! So every manipulation by JS comes afterwards.

Comment: Yeah? Why couldn't Respond.js copy the full CSS with the replaced MQ instead of just the MQ parts? That would work well, don't you think?

Comment: Btw. I already poured that suggestion into their issue thread.

Comment: No, it wouldn't! Simply because there is also no way to "erase" any CSS styles the browser once knew. The only option is to "override" them. But how should respond.js do this? Maybe the order was intended by the author? And if not, why should the script do the work for you? This would make the script only bigger in size and slower in execution. In the end it's your job to write all in the right order. ;-)

Comment: That's why I said the script should copy the whole CSS. ;)

Comment: That wouldn't change anything. As the word "copy" already implies, does the browser already know about the CSS. You cannot make him forget about it. A browser that does not support/ understand media queries ignores them just as if they were not there. The script "analyses" which MQs "matches" and **adds** their styles/ rules - just without the MQ itself. So they will always be **appended**! Sorry, but there is no other way - believe it or not! ;-)

Comment: OK, please do me a favor and at least try to understand what I'm saying instead of being cheeky. I said: 1. the script should copy the whole CSS. 2. It should reduce all media queries inside to the relevant set. 3. Remove all media query declarations but leave its content as is. 4. Remove the original CSS file. Et voila. Simple solution, right?

Comment: Point 4 is the thing which is not possible (I tried before to explain why). So **all** rules that the browser understands are already present and **couldn't be deleted** - no way! So the rules inside the media queries, which the browser didn't understand while processing the rules, they can only be appended at the end of all other rules. You cannot avoid this order. The browser has some kind of "memory", which causes or enables him to never forget any rule he once has known. Sorry, my English skills aren't goog enough to explain it any better.

Comment: PS: I just remembered an example which might illustrate what I try to explain? Set up a small HTML file (e.g. as jsFiddle) with a `<style>` element and write a CSS rule inside. Then change the `innerHTML` of the style element with a new rule or even delete its content completely. And you will see that the original rule is still present/ known by the browser. Hope this makes it a little clearer.

Comment: Yes but the point is you don't have to delete the original file. It's just pointless from that moment when you applied the full copy with the stripped media queries. Which will also override all memories as a desired side effect.

Answer (score 0):

a **quick and dirty** solution should be:

```
/* Will be overridden by respond.js */
.shouldBeGreen {
  background-color: green;
  @media screen and (min-width: 50px) {
    background-color: green; //force green for respond.js
  }
}
```

In this way respond.js, that apply rules always AFTER normal css styling, is forced to apply green at run time.